# Is there Angular compatible WYSIWYG libraries that allow to save the text with markup as well as uploaded images as the single data stream?

Tags: angular, wysiwyg

I'd like to develop the blog feature of the web application which should be secondary comparing to the main features. Admins, using blogs can post small texts with reach formatting and post small photos inserted to the text. Is there some Angular WYSISYG libraries that can provide the text markup together with base64-encoded images to be saved as a single string entry on the backend?

Comment: If this is a large scale or production application, be weary that base 64 encoded images saved as such are a huge drag on performance. Blog posts with a lot of images are going to be very slow.

Comment: @bryan60 for sure, no. Just brief admin's notes with some gif pics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in the previous answer doesn't cover all possible use cases.

There is a bug triggered by pasting some content (like a section of a word file) that contains more than one image. The code needs to be updated so that the image to convert in base64 will always be the correct one. Selecting the image with `editor.image.get()` only inside the `onload` callback results in a race condition that makes it so the first image will almost always replace every other image the user is pasting in the editor.

A corrected version of the code is as follows:

```js
public options: Object = {
    placeholderText: 'Edit Your Content Here!',
    charCounterCount: true,
    toolbarButtonsXS: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'alert'],
    toolbarButtonsSM: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'alert'],
    toolbarButtonsMD: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'alert'],
    toolbarButtons: ['uploadFile', 'fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent'],
    events: {
        'image.beforeUpload': function (files) {
            const editor = this;
            if (files.length) {
                const image = editor.image.get();
                // Create a File Reader.
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    var result = reader.result;
                    editor.image.insert(result, null, null, image);
                };
                // Read image as base64.
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                console.log("Behind event");
                // Read image as base64.
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            }
            //editor.popups.hideAll();
            // Stop default upload chain.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like froala allows this:

https://wysiwyg-editor.froala.help/hc/en-us/articles/115000555949-Can-I-insert-images-as-base64-

but note, that the JS example will not work for the TypeScript as is.

You should change it a bit due to: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4163

that should be associated with the editor parameter like this:

```
<textarea [froalaEditor]="options" [(froalaModel)]="editorContent"></textarea>
```

and placed to you component code:

```
public options:Object = {
    placeholderText: 'Edit Your Content Here!',
    charCounterCount: true,
    toolbarButtonsXS: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'alert'],
    toolbarButtonsSM: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'alert'],
    toolbarButtonsMD: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'alert'],
    toolbarButtons: ['uploadFile', 'fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent'],
    events: {
      'image.beforeUpload': function(files) {
    console.log("Start");
    const editor = this;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log("Files: "+files.length);
      // Create a File Reader.
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        var result = reader.result;
        editor.image.insert(result, null, null, editor.image.get());
      };
      // Read image as base64.
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      console.log("Behind event");
      // Read image as base64.
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
    //editor.popups.hideAll();
    // Stop default upload chain.
    return false;
  }
```

}

Comment: There is a caveat here if a user pastes something containing multiple images, like a section from a word file contianing more than one image. Using this code the first image would overwrite all the others because of a race condition.
In order to solve the issue you have to move the `editor.image.get()` outside of the onload callback, so that it willa lways select the right image. Please consider modifying your answer to take this case into account!

Comment: @TrinTragula currently can't check and debug it, but I'ld like you to provide the final code snipped as a separate answer and I'd like to prefer make it as a true answer